# WPF MVVM Data Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic

I am new to WPF and MVVM and I have a few questions.

I am looking at a "simple" project to start after doing much reading and a few simple apps.

What I want to do is be able to display data from a database table. Seems simple enough and I can do this with a Model based on each field from the database. But what happens if the database developer adds additional fields??? I have to recreate my Model based on the new fields.

So my question is this. How do I read all fields from a database and display them.
can I create a dynamic model from the database rather than a fixed model??

Is MVVM or even WPF the correct format for this type of application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not do this personally. Adding a field in a table is a breaking change, you don't want it to magically appear in your application without model/view/etc modifications. A simple example: what label would you use as column header for the new field? The field name using reflection? Nah, no real world application would do that.

Comment: The only scenario I can think of where this would be valid is a custom SQL tool, where you let you user write the query and then display the results. Otherwise, the advice given already is solid.  If you want to do that, you are as well to use a gridview bound to the dataset.

Comment: If a Developer adds new fields to the database and those fields are relevant to your screen it would seem perfectly fine to expect that programmer to add those fields to the model? That's how we work here in a professional setting anyway. What about the other way around? What if the programmer added a field you did NOT want to show? Your approach leaves you stranded one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keen on using that approach, I guess the "simple" way to do it would be to read the data like this: "SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE" and then fill the result into a datatable. That datatable can then serve as the data source for the gridview, which needs to keep it's autogenerateColumns property set to true. This way it would always show all the columns returned, though this is usually not the practice, since you can't template the columns - but for some cases it's good enough.